# Typescript print PDF file does not displays the FileName while saving as PDF

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, iframe, printing

In Angular application backend file response is of Blob type. Using IFrame I am able to print the file but when I select save as PDF. The screen shows a random name fetched from the url.

Like - 1231-35677-345.pdf

But I want the name by default to be displayed as Summary.pdf

My code -

```
const newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: type });
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = fileURL;
iframe.name = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

```
const newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: type });
let fileName = "Summary";
FileSaver.saveAs(newBlob , `${fileName}.pdf`);
```